# git-diff with .gitattributes in a bare repository

Tags: git, git-diff

I use gitea for storing my code and noticed that it doesn't obey `.gitattributes` when diffing.

Having looked into this it seems to be an issue with bare repos. I found some information on [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/3676) that suggests using the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environmental variable.

```bash
repo.git # GIT_INDEX_FILE=tmp_index git read-tree --reset -i testing-attributes
repo.git # GIT_INDEX_FILE=tmp_index git check-attr --cached --all ent/actions.go
ent/actions.go: diff: unset
ent/actions.go: merge: unset
```

This seems to work for `check-attr` but I can't seem to get it to work with git diff.

```bash
GIT_INDEX_FILE=tmp_index git diff c165f76c8c 71ecf0a90b
```

```patch
diff --git a/ent/action.go b/ent/action.go
index 7d4edbe..4b71332 100644
--- a/ent/action.go
+++ b/ent/action.go
@@ -18,6 +18,8 @@ type Action struct {
        ID int `json:"id,omitempty"`
        // Name holds the value of the "name" field.
        Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
+       // Name1 holds the value of the "name1" field.
+       Name1 string `json:"name1,omitempty"`
        // Edges holds the relations/edges for other nodes in the graph.
        // The values are being populated by the ActionQuery when eager-loading is set.
        Edges        ActionEdges `json:"edges"`
```

The diff still displays changes in files that have the `-diff` attribute set on them. I would expect to see

```patch
diff --git a/ent/action.go b/ent/action.go
index 7d4edbe..4b71332 100644
Binary files a/ent/action.go and b/ent/action.go differ
```

Comment: `git check-attr --cached` [considers](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr#Documentation/git-check-attr.txt---cached) `.gitattributes` in the index only, ignoring the working tree; this is exactly right for a bare repo. `git diff` doesn't have such a flag, it requires `.gitattributes` to be a file; in a bare repo it could be [`$ROOT/info/attributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) or [global](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreattributesFile) file but not `.gitattributes` from any commit.

Comment: Did you do the `git read-tree` before the `git diff`? If so, @phd's comment must be the answer. The Git documentation is a bit light on whether the index copy of `.gitattributes` is used when there not only isn't a working tree copy now, but there *can't* be one because there is no working tree. The [existing documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) says that the index copy is used as a "fall-back", which seems to imply that the index copy *should* be used even in a bare repository.

Comment: Meanwhile, if all you want to know is whether two resolve-able commit-and-path strings represent the same content, or different content, consider just using `git rev-parse` on the two strings. For instance, `git rev-parse branch1:path/to/file.go` and `git rev-parse branch2:other/file`. This will give you two blob hash IDs (assuming these are blob objects). If the hashes are the same, the contents are the same; if not, the contents differ.

Comment: @phd I had seen in the docs that `--cached` isn't available on `git diff` but I had read the man page as @torek has in that the index should be used as a "fallback" option so had hoped it might work. `git diff` is called on the gitea server using the two commits hashes to generate the diff in the browser - unfortunately I'm not sure the blob technique would work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That should be supported with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), since the attribute subsystem learned to honor `attr.tree` configuration that specifies which tree to read the `.gitattributes` files from.

See [commit 9f9c40c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f9c40cf34c29d4ad700d9869435d159056fa6fb), [commit 2386535](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2386535511d1181afd4e892e2a866ffe5e1d7d21) (13 Oct 2023) by [John Cai (`john-cai`)](https://github.com/john-cai).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 26dd307](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26dd307cfaabe3d3f0b01aad64969e76a317811a), 30 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`attr`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2386535511d1181afd4e892e2a866ffe5e1d7d21): read attributes from HEAD when bare repo
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: John Cai</sup>

> The motivation for [44451a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44451a2e5eec5360378be23e2cdbd9ecee49e14e) (`attr`: teach , 2023-05-06, Git v2.41.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67a3b2b39f638872531324e03217fa58f7b9ad1e)) (attr: teach "--attr-source=" global option to "git" , 2023-05-06), was to make it possible to use `gitattributes` with bare repositories.
>
> To make it easier to read `gitattributes` in bare repositories however, let's just make HEAD:.gitattributes the default.
> This is in line with how mailmap works, [8c473ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c473cecfd8835c2bdf34b323e1b2de620099c04) ("`mailmap`: default mailmap.blob in bare repositories", 2012-12-13, Git v1.8.2-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a3100a889cab5d3a1a590258304dacd188a17f6)).

Example:

```
cd /path/to/bare/repository.git
git -c attr.tree=HEAD check-attr -- test
```

`git diff` should benefit from `git check-attr` new capability.